# increase width and height of td cells in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to increase the width and height of the td cells as per my requirement.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="margin-top-10">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;"><?php echo $this->remarksForm->remarkType; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->remarksForm->remark; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php  echo $this->remarksForm->id;
                    echo $this->remarksForm->save; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result of what I have now:
[image]

Here is an image of the result what I would like to get:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Yesterday I saw this question, anyway now the button is not dropping, I suppose you should be using the textarea tag instead of input type="text", remove any height from styling to it. use vertical-align: top for all elements.

Comment: you mean for all td need to use vertical align:top

Comment: okay then what about the middle one how can increase the height  of that td

Comment: They are usually middle aligned right. If you want them to be aligned to top then try it. I do not like to move elements with negative margins and transform, translate just for alignment.

Comment: so how can i increse it..is there a any other way

Comment: textarea will naturally take two lines space minimum, no need of explicit height as far as I know.

Comment: hope this will help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: i have not understand how to use that..can you please explain me.. how can i use it in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example :

```
    <div class="margin-top-10">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;"><select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;"><textarea></textarea></td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                   <button>thank you</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: reference image for the posters desired alignment for the above html.]

Comment: but mine is not textarea its not textbox

Comment: if i use text area the text box coming too big and add button goes off from div

Comment: Its table and I do not know what suits best in the situation textarea or input type text but if it is too big then please check corresponding styling upon the element like widths or size as you are trying to use php you might have different options by default try with bear minimum code and compare the output html's you will find the solution.

Comment: somehow its working i changes it to textaea  and added rows and cols

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this style:

```
height: 50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please add width:
    <div class="margin-top-10">
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" style="vertical-align:top;">test</td>
                <td width="70%">test</td>
                <td width="10%">test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So I think your inner element taking width so please can you share URL.

Comment: its in local so sorry i cant give you link